# How can I manage which applications are handled by cerbere?

Tags: cerbere

I would like to add/remove applications from the list of those handled by `cerbere`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can manage Cerbere's list.

### Graphical Option:

You will need `dconf-editor` in order to use this option. To install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Or, install it via the Software Center.

---

- Once it is installed, run `dconf-editor`. You will be presented with a window like this:

  [image]
- Now you need to find `org.pantheon.cerbere`

  [image]
- You can add any application you want, but **take note**: *Any application you add will restart as soon as it is closed. Some applications can be resource intensive and should be avoided.*

---

### Text-based (Command-line) Option:

You will need to run a command like this:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.cerbere monitored-processes ['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent']
```

But edit the list of items, so for example, to add Google Chrome:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.cerbere monitored-processes ['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent','google-chrome']
```

to reset it run this command:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.cerbere monitored-processes
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update that at least as of elementary OS 6 (Odin), this schema appears to be missing. Couldn’t find anything for cerbere in gsettings.

```
gsettings list-keys org.pantheon.cerbere
```

Results in:

```
No such schema “org.pantheon.cerbere”
```

Anyone know where these settings have moved?

(I looked around a bit and can’t seem to find them. Instructions, e.g., https://gitlab.com/pantheon-debian/cerbere/-/blob/pantheon-debian-daily/debian/io.elementary.cerbere.1, all seem outdated.)

(Use case: just need to hide wingpanel top bar temporarily to take a screenshot without it and thought I’d do it by having cerbere stop watching wingpanel instead of killing it outright.)